# Change all metadata property error messages for StringLengthAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can I modify all properties StringLengthAttribute error message of a modelmetadata ? I can change one by one by calling GetValidators().

Here is my htmlhelper code:

```
public static HtmlString TestHelper<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> pFieldExpression)
    {
        ModelMetadata fieldmetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(pFieldExpression, html.ViewData);

        // option 1
        var a = (from s in fieldmetadata.ModelType.GetProperties()
                  select s.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute), true)
                 );
        foreach (var i in a)
        {
            // ther is no error message
        }


        // option 2
        var validatorsDictionary = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers
                                                     .GetValidators(fieldmetadata, html.ViewContext)
                                                     .SelectMany(v => v.GetClientValidationRules());
        // validatorsDictionary is empty and seems cannot modify metadata

        return new HtmlString("test");
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want to globally change the default error message to a custom one? (not sure what the code you have shown has to do with it)

Comment: Yes, i do want to change error message of all properties of a model metadata but not sure how to do it.  In option 1, I got StringLengthAttribute of all properties and updated the error message.But it changed back to default.